# Biblatex authoryear style is printing numerical citations

Tags: biblatex

Here is my `biblatex` setting in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, 
firstinits=true, 
maxbibnames=5, 
maxcitenames=2, 
sorting=nyt, 
url=false, 
isbn=false, 
eprint=false, 
doi=false, 
dashed=false, 
natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Still, my citations are being printed numerically e.g. `[2]`, `[72,58]` etc.  I have cleared all the `aux`, and `bbl` files and tried recompiling, but still getting same results.  The references are being printed correctly and strangely enough, they don't have numbers.  So there is a complete disconnect between citations and references.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: There is also no need to put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Load biblatex with `style=authoryear`. The default is `style=numeric` or equivalently `bibstyle=numeric` and `citestyle=numeric`. Just setting `bibstyle=authoryear` doesn't change `citestyle=numeric`.

Comment: @cryptic0 No problem. If you find the manual too overwhelming, you can try looking over the examples that come with the biblatex documentation.