# How to create a numbered list of references when using verbose-trad1 style with the biblatex package?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, numbering

I am using the biblatex package in the verbose-trad1 style.

When generating a bibliography at the end of my chapter, all references are listed in alphabetical author, but they are NOT numbered.

Is there a way to have all references numbered? That way, the readers would also have an idea of the number of references in the bibliography.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Thank you for this information Guido. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6):

There are different commands for biblatex to have different styles for citations and the bibliography. For example you can have

```
\usepackage[
    citestyle=verbose-trad1,  % Your citation style.
    bibstyle=numeric,         % Style for bibliography list. It will be numeric.
    sorting=none,             % The citations will be listed in the order of appearance
    backend=biber             % This is not necessary for newer versions of biblatex as 
                              % it is the default, but it certainly helps to keep things
                              % explicit.
]{biblatex}
```

For different sorting schemes refer to the [p.52 of Biblatex guide](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

---

I guess, that there are also several somewhat related questions on TeX.SX:

- [biblatex: Different formatting for citations v. bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/biblatex-different-formatting-for-citations-v-bibliography/30910#30910)
- [Biblatex entries with last names first and year after authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36240/biblatex-entries-with-last-names-first-and-year-after-authors/36247#36247)
- [Biblatex authoryear style is printing numerical citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95809/biblatex-authoryear-style-is-printing-numerical-citations/95811#95811)

Maybe these will be helpful as well.

Comment: Making a distinction between citestyle and bibstyle in my preamble indeed helped to generate a numbered reference list.

However, due to numeric style now chosen, it also removed the dashes that were normally used to replace recurrent authors/editors in the bibliography, thus visually grouping items by the same author or editor. I have tried to re-enable this feature by adding dashed=true in my preamble, but this did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I understand, the `dashed` option is available only for `verbose`, `authoryear` and `authortitle` styles. Currently, I do not have any suggestions how to solve the problem. Either way, why do you need to number your citations in the bibliography list?